# How make that works load and ready together

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, load

I have this code... i load in `<head>` many files.js, this works good... but ... `{{sec-intro}}` is a variable and has its value, but does not load the file...

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        jQuery('head').load( 'tpl/head.html' );
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#intro').load( 'tpl/sec-intro-{{sec-intro}}.html' );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `{{sec-intro}}` is no regular JS-variable. Looks like an angularJS placeholder.

Comment: i know sir, the problem is not with {{variable}}. The .load don't works, i think is a problem with the time execution (DOM), i think too that i don't using correctly the .ready, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I know what do you mean but you can try this if sec-intro is a javascript variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#intro').load( 'tpl/sec-intro-' + sec-intro + '.html' );
    });
</script>
```

But I think you are confusing with AngularJS notation that uses {{var}}.

EDIT:

Well, first of all variable name can't have hyphen so you need to change that name.

Second thing, you should declare the function in the controller's code.  I did a little angular app that is the code:

Script:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.secintro = '01';

  $scope.loadFunction = function(){
    jQuery('#intro').load('tpl/sec-intro-' + $scope.secintro + '.html');
  };

  $scope.loadFunction();
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.0.8"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  </body>

</html>
```

Then you can use loadFunction as angularJS function, i.e: ng-init="loadFunction();"

```
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="loadFunction();">

  </body>
```

This will execute the function when controller is ready, so you won't need the `$scope.loadFunction();` inicialization.

[Here is the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RLuJFf0t5rTRQFEkJnbX) just print in console the correct string.

I hope this finally works for you.

Comment: Excuse me sir, I'm not an advanced programmer ... I see in firebug that sec-intro takes its value well, but the .load does not load the .html file, thank you

Comment: In the code that you provide I can't imagine how 'tpl/sec-intro-{{sec-intro}}.html' can be different string since you don't replace {{sec-intro}} with other string. We need more information. You can use `console.log('tpl/sec-intro-{{sec-intro}}.html')` to see in console what value takes in runtime.

Comment: In Firebug I see it this way

`$ (Document) .ready (function () {
jQuery ('# intro') load ('tpl / intro-sec-01.html.');
})`

that is {{sec-intro}} takes either the value '01'

but the .load does not load the html ...

if I change {{sec-intro}} for 01 directly in the code

.load then yes it works well ...

Comment: I think you are using angularJS or similar framework that replace the variable, so I guess the replace action is executed after script execute. Try this: `<script type="text/javascript">
var url = 'tpl/sec-intro-{{sec-intro}}.html';
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#intro').load(url);
    });
</script>` This is all I can suggest with the information I have. I hope this works for you.

Comment: It's doesn't work... :( in firebug the result is this `<script type="text/javascript">
var url = 'tpl/sec-intro-01.html';
$( document ).ready(function() {
jQuery('#intro').load(url); });
</script>`

Comment: Please, try this and tell me what you get in firebug console: `<script type="text/javascript"> var url = 'tpl/sec-intro-{{sec-intro}}.html'; $( document ).ready(function() { console.log(url);  jQuery('#intro').load(url); }); </script>` But if you are using angularJS are other ways to do that in the controllers code with $scope function, etc.

Comment: On the console, the variable is not loaded `tpl/sec-intro-{{sec-intro}}.html`. To me everything worked fine, the problems started when I started using .load, if I put all the code on the same page variable {{variable}} works fine... excuse my english